# Rails 4: set a contact form in the homepage (one page layout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, contact-form

I am working on a one page website and I would like to implement a easy contact form for the users at the bottom of the page.

I am new to rails, so I began following a tutorial and everything works nice.
this is the tutorial:
http://l4u.github.io/articles/create-a-rails-4-site-with-contact-us-form/

So what I have now is a homepage with a link to a new page (the contact page) where the form is displayed.

But I have to 'move' the contact form from the 'contact' page to my 'index/home' one page.

If anybody could help with the logic of the form, controllers and models it could be great!

Comment: Could you show the code? Generally, I would render the form partial on the proper page using either an instantiated instance variable or a form for a new object.